# How do I create my c sharp object to match my RestSharp XML response?

Tags: c#, xml, object, restsharp

I just started to work with RestSharp and using the NextFlix API have been able to successfully create my Oauth tokens and request data from NetFlix.  But for some reason I can not seem to create my objects to match the return XML correctly.

My code:

```
    var client2 = new RestClient("http://api-public.netflix.com")
        {
            Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(MyOauth.ConsumerKey, MyOauth.ConsumerSecret, MyOauth.OauthToken, MyOauth.OauthTokenSecret)
        };

        var request = new RestRequest("/catalog/titles/autocomplete");
        request.AddParameter("term", "star wars");
        var searchResults = client2.Execute<CatalogList>(request);
```

My attempted object creation:

```
  [XmlRoot("autocomplete")]
    public class CatalogList
    {
        public List<AutoCompleteItem> Titles { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("autocomplete_item")]
    public class AutoCompleteItem
    {
        [XmlElement("title short")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("short")]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
    }
```

serachresults returns 20 titles and my List has 20 entries, however the AutoCompleteItem is always empty.  I've changed up the element names, attributes etc but never get the right combination.

The XML that is returned looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
<autocomplete>
<url_template>http://api-public.netflix.com/catalog/titles/autocomplete?{-join|&|term}   </url_template> 
<autocomplete_item>
<title short="Star Wars: Episode II: Attack of the Clones" /> 
</autocomplete_item>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot("autocomplete")]
public class AutocompleteList
{
    [XmlElement("url_template")]
    public string UrlTemplate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("autocomplete_item")]
    public List<AutocompleteItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class AutocompleteItem
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public Title ItemTitle { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    [XmlAttribute("short")]
    public string Short { get; set; }
}
```

The inner `Title` type is necessary to be able to capture the XML attribute `short=`.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""yes"" ?>
<autocomplete>
    <url_template>http://api-public.netflix.com/catalog/titles/autocomplete?{-join|&amp;|term}</url_template>
    <autocomplete_item>
        <title short=""Star Wars: Episode II: Attack of the Clones"" />
    </autocomplete_item>
</autocomplete>";

var reader = new StringReader(xml);
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AutocompleteList));

var result = (AutocompleteList) ser.Deserialize(reader);
```

This produces the same result as

```
var result = new AutocompleteList
{
    UrlTemplate = "http://api-public.netflix.com/catalog/titles/autocomplete?{-join|&|term}",
    Items = new List<AutocompleteItem>
    {
        new AutocompleteItem
        {
            ItemTitle = new Title
            {
                Short = "Star Wars: Episode II: Attack of the Clones",
            }
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: I now get the URL template, but ItemTitle (all 20 of them) show up as null.  Is it possible the RestSharp deserializer isn't functioning correctly and I need to do it on my own?  Or does the object need to be tweaked?  Thanks for the help..

Comment: your code works fine when deserializing the xml manually.. I guess I'll just go that route.  No idea why RestSharp isn't functioning with it.  Probably user error I'm sure.  But thanks again.